# Errores con jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, json

Estoy realizando una página web en la cual estoy utilizando jQuery (más específicamente esta librería: https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js).

Tengo esta función:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var documento=prueba;
        function obtener_modificacion(){
            $.ajax({                        
                type:"POST",                 
                url:"modificaraprendiz.php",
                success: function(data)             
                {
                    $('#page').html(data);               
                }
            });
        }
       $(document).on("click", "#modificar", function(){
            $.ajax({
                type:"post",
                url:"modificaraprendiz.php",
                data:{doc:documento},
                success: function(data){
                    obtener_modificacion();
                }
            })
        });
    });
```

Me funciona casi todo correctamente: Me trae la página que quiero, las variables se definen bien. El problema está, en que cuando me trae la página, me aparece el error del índice indefinido (ya que la página que llamo, es una consulta directamente).

```
<?php
  include('conexion.php');
  $doc=$_POST['doc'];
?>
```

Así es cómo lo recibo, pero me muestra el siguiente error

> Notice: Undefined index: doc on line 3.

Comment: tu error es PHP no jQuery

Answer (score 0):

no estas enviando nada por metodo post debes usar el metodo `data` de jquery ajax para que se defina `$_POST["doc"]` con lo que quieres o utilizar el metodo `isset($_POST["doc"])` para validar que este definido!:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
            var documento="prueba";
            var data = {"doc":"lo_que enviaras"};
            function obtener_modificacion(){
                $.ajax({                        
                    type:"POST",
                    data:data,               
                    url:"modificaraprendiz.php",
                    success: function(data)             
                    {
                        $('#page').html(data);               
                    }
                });
            }
           $(document).on("click", "#modificar", function(){
                $.ajax({
                    type:"post",
                    url:"modificaraprendiz.php",
                    data:data ,
                    success: function(data){
                        obtener_modificacion();
                    }
                })
            });
        });
```

Comment: Gracias, amigo. Me ayudaste bastante. De verdad te agradezco.

Comment: Oye, disculpa la molestia, pero quisiera preguntarte cómo sería el caso de que la variable data me tome 2 valores de unos input.

Yo lo intenté así, pero no funcionó:

var data={"doc":$("#documento").val(), "tipo":$("#tipodoc").val()}

Comment: esta bien pero por lo general si vas a enviar datos es mas facil hacerlo asi `var data = $( "form" ).serialize();`

Comment: ¿Pero para ello tengo que tener un <form>? Porque en ninguna de mis páginas las utilizo. Sólo el JavaScript.

Comment: si pero un form no cambia visualmente nada en tu pagina :v

Comment: Jajaja. Pero entonces no le pongo un método. Jajajaj. Muchas gracias, de verdad. Soy nuevo en esto de JavaScript.

Comment: Y el problema es que ya lo intenté y ya no me muestra el '[object HTML]', pero no funciona aún. Me muestra las variables, pero no los datos. Disculpa la molestia.

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que veo en el código y en el errores que falta declarar la variable *doc*:

```
 $(document).on("click", "#modificar", function(){
       var doc = "palabra, valor o consulta";
        $.ajax({
            type:"post",
            url:"modificaraprendiz.php",
            data:{doc:documento},
            success: function(data){
                obtener_modificacion();
            }
        })
    });
```

Por eso es que aparece el error. Por que no estaba declarada la variable en el envió de ella.

Comment: Sí, está previamente definida. Igual, con un dato exacto, no funciona.